# Multisort/Sort grid with AjaxStore

Tags: oracle, sorting, extjs, extjs4.2

i need to implement the multisort in grid that populate from a Ajax Store, but i have also a problem with the simple sorting of column.

This is my store:

```
dsUser = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'user',
        pageSize: defPagSize,
        totalProperty: 'totalCount',
        autoLoad: {start: 0, limit: defPagSize},
        remoteSort: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            enablePaging:true,
            url: '<c:url value="/queryForList.action?query=User.getUsers"/>',
            reader: {
                         type: 'json',
                         root: 'list',
                         totalProperty:'totalCount'
            }
        }
});
```

Anytype of help is usefull.
Thanks.

EDIT:
Now i re-write the old logic of sorting in my application..At this moment i find anyone can help me to post and modify grid for posting an array of (property:'', direction:'') and mantain the icon on the grid to select. (sorry for my english)

Answer (score 1):

The proxy is merely sending through the sortParam and value in a structure that is usable in JS...e.g., a JSON-encoded array of objects ([{"property":"email","direction":"DESC"}]).

When you receive this request server-side, you'll absolutely need top parse apart the sort order object and convert it to a string that your DB can understand. Using the raw value from the query string in your DB will not work, nor was it intended to work like that.

When I do this, it's typically like this:

- Receive request
- Search for sort order param in query string
- Decode the JSON string into an object in my server-side app's language
- Iterate over the array of sorters and build a "sort" string
- Send parsed sort string along to the DB query